# Delete duplicate rows GROUP BY with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, json, group-by, duplicates

I have a string in database (mysql) which is like:

```
{"StateId":73,"CallTime":"\/Date(1336365498912+0500)\/","CallId":"1336365489.14157","Target":"agi://127.0.0.1"}},"Profile":{"$type":"DataWriter.DbProfile, DataWriterObjects","Name":"DataService","Provider":"mssql","ConnectionString":"Data Source=localhost\\mydb; Database=mydb; User Id=sa; Password=admin;"}}
```

The string is a JSON object which contains multiple fields. The problem is that I have multiple duplicate rows which I want to remove from the database. A row is considered a duplicate if the **CallId** and **StateId** is same but the **CallTime** is different. So first I want to get list of the duplicates (GROUP BY) of those rows which have **CallId** same and ignore the difference in **CallTime**. The below record has different **CallTime** from the first one but same **CallId**, hence it is considered a duplicate (basically need not to consider **CallTime** for duplicate)

```
{"StateId":73,"CallTime":"\/Date(1336365498913+0500)\/","CallId":"1336365489.14157","Target":"agi://127.0.0.1"}},"Profile":{"$type":"DataWriter.DbProfile, DataWriterObjects","Name":"DataService","Provider":"mssql","ConnectionString":"Data Source=localhost\\mydb; Database=mydb; User Id=sa; Password=admin;"}}
```

So how do I do a GROUP BY? Basically everything in the GROUP BY should be matched ignoring the **CallTime** value.

The table structure is

```
mysql> describe Statements;

+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SequenceId | bigint(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Profile    | varchar(32) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| CacheItem  | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

After that I want to delete the duplicates. Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your database is not atomic enough, you may have to split out your JSON string into separate fields